# How to get the next item in a seq (sequence)?

Tags: alloy

An airplane flies a sequence of legs. Each leg must be followed by an appropriate next leg. A `NextLegTable` contains the appropriate (`Leg -> Leg`) pairs.

So, each pair of legs in a flight must be in the `NextLegTable`. I implemented this constraint in the below `Fact`.

Here is a description of my implementation: Each pair of legs (`leg` and `leg'`), such that `indexOf(leg) + 1 = indexOf(leg')`, must be in the `NextLegTable`. Apparently that approach is wrong, as I get "no instances."

What is the right approach? Given a leg, how do I find its next leg in the sequence?

```
sig Flight {
    legs: seq Leg
}

sig Leg {}

one sig NextLegTable {
    nextLeg: Leg -> Leg
}

fact Flight_legs_In_NexLegTable {
    all f: Flight |
        all leg, leg': Leg { 
            leg in f.legs.elems
            leg' in f.legs.elems 
            plus[f.legs.idxOf[leg], 1] =  f.legs.idxOf[leg']
            (leg -> leg') in NextLegTable.nextLeg
        }
}

pred Show (f: Flight) {#f.legs > 1} 
run Show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the two lines to look at:

```
    plus[f.legs.idxOf[leg], 1] =  f.legs.idxOf[leg']
    (leg -> leg') in NextLegTable.nextLeg
```

This solution is currently attempting to find an instance where all `Legs` of a `Flight` that follow another `Leg` are also shown in the `NextLegTable` sig. However, you have not told it to actually put these mappings into the table. You need to say that when a `Leg` follows another `Leg`, put `Leg -> Leg'` into NextLegTable:

```
(plus[f.legs.idxOf[leg], 1] =  f.legs.idxOf[leg']) =>
(leg -> leg') in NextLegTable.nextLeg
```

This tells the program to place the mappings into the table whenever the first condition is met.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you LEJ